# Haskell: Multiple long-running `callCommand "sudo ..."`

Tags: haskell, sudo

I have a Haskell script that runs long-running some shell commands with `sudo`:

```
do callCommand "sudo somethingLong"
   callCommand "sudo somethingElseLong"
```

Problem is, it asks for my password for each invocation of `callCommand "sudo ..."`. For short-running command this isn't a problem, but if they are long enough it'll ask again.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour? So it just asks for my password once until the script is done?

Comment: Haha yes definitely, mostly the choice for Haskell was for fun, and just to try it out. It is indeed not very well fitted for this, but it does work (other than this one annoyance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `sudo` "security policy" is to cache credentials on a per-terminal basis for 15 minutes.  As long as a `sudo` command is executed on the terminal at an interval that's less than 15 minutes, you should be able to maintain the cached credentials.  Also, `sudo` provides a `-v` flag (short for `--validate`) that refreshes the credentials without actually running a command.

So, you need to arrange to run `sudo -v` every, say, 10 minutes while your Haskell script is running.  You can do this by forking a thread that runs `forever`.  Something like the following ought to work:

```
import System.Process
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent

main = do
  forkIO $ forever $ do               -- do this forever
    threadDelay 600000000             -- wait 10 minutes
    callCommand "sudo -v"             -- refresh credentials
  callCommand "sudo sleep 1200"       -- wait 20 minutes
  callCommand "sudo cat /etc/passwd"
```

In my test, I was prompted for a password when the program started (i.e., in order to run `sudo sleep 1200`), but even though that slept for 20 minutes (long enough for the credentials to expire), the `sudo -v` that ran after only 10 minutes kept the credentials valid, so the `sudo cat /etc/passwd` command ran without prompting.

Note that, when the main thread exits, the forked thread is automatically killed.  If this was part of a larger program where you wanted to keep credentials alive for a limited amount of time and then allow them to expire while the main program kept running, you'd want store the thread ID of the forked thread and kill it when you were done, like so:

```
main = do
  t <- forkIO $ forever $ do          -- save the ID of the thread
    threadDelay 600000000
    callCommand "sudo -v"
  callCommand "sudo sleep 1200"
  callCommand "sudo cat /etc/passwd"
  killThread t                        -- stop refreshing credentials
  -- ...
  -- do more stuff, without refreshing credentials
  -- ...
```